# libssh2 Agent forwarding not working

Tags: ios, ssh, terminal, libssh2, ssh-agent

I am using `libssh2` library to ssh connections in my mobile application. Here I want to use `Agent Forwarding` support.

I have followed same procedure as they have provided in example here [LibSSH2 Agent Forwarding](http://www.libssh2.org/examples/ssh2_agent.html).

I am able to create agent successfully but when I try to connect it with `libssh2_agent_connect(agent)` It gives me error **-39** `LIBSSH2_ERROR_BAD_USE`.

Well I am checking same thing using **MAC OSX terminal** and it's working fine. Please suggest if anything wrong,

What I am doing is:

- I have Machine A, MAchine B, Machine C.
- I am creating RSA Key on default location in Machine A, I am adding
  that key to agent on Machine A, I can show added identity too with
  agent.
- Copying public key (which created in machine A and added in agent) in
  Machine B and Machine C. Now I can ssh with Machine B and Machine C
  without enter pass phrase of that key.

That means agent forwarding is working fine correct? Please suggest me if anything wrong in above flow. I am very new to ssh sorry if this is obvious.

I am doing same thing with libssh2, making connection with Machine B with same key which copied in machine B. Please suggest am I missing anything using libssh2 lib to forward agent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

LibSSH2 does not currently support agent forwarding. There is an  [open request](https://github.com/libssh2/libssh2/issues/185) for that feature.

The example linked above is for standard SSH agent authentication, sans forwarding.